# I am trying to connect to a server through RMI but is is not working

Tags: java, rmi

The server address is 192.168.0.104. When I try to connect the client program gives the folowing exception:

```
C:\Users\Atreya\Desktop>java -jar Clientjar.jar
Enter IP address of server
192.168.0.104
Client exception: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 169.254
.111.240; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 169.254.111.240; nested e
xception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at RMIClient.main(RMIClient.java:18)
```

Now 169.254.111.240 is the auto configuration ipv4 address of the client machine's Ethernet adapter.

Comment: Did you try telnet to above IP address? Does your system is able to reach above IP address?

Comment: I pinged it. And both the machines are connected. @PradeepSimha

Comment: @PradeepSimha If the address wasn't reachable it would have been a different error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no RMI Registry running at 169.254.111.240 on whatever port you are using, by default port 1099.